# uppercase letter input can't working in cpp programs

Tags: c++

I am reading C++ right now ,and got stuck in the following program.

When I provide string with lower case letter, it provides a fine output, but when I go for upper case letters, it gets stuck after the input.

Here is the code:

```
`#include <iostream>`
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include "string.h"

using namespace std;

class base {
public:
int array(){
    int i, n, p, z = 0;
    char g[50];
    string c[50];
    char abc;

    cout << "Enter the name :" << endl;
    cin >> g;

    i = 0;
    while (g[i] != 0)
        if ((g[i] >= 'a' && g[i] <= 'z') || (g[i] <= 'A' && g[i] >= 'Z')){
            z++;
            i++;
        }
    cout << "name is of " << z << " elements" << endl;
    {
        for (p = 0; p < z; p++)
            cout << "a[" << p + 1 << "]=" << g[p] << endl;
    }
    cout << "enter the element no.:";
    cin >> n;
    if(n >0 && n <= z){
        cout << "a[" << n << "]=" << g[n-1] << endl;
    }
    for (p = 0; p < z; p++){
        char integer_string[50];
        int integer = p+1;

        sprintf(integer_string, "%d", integer);
        char other_string[50] = "g[";
        strcat(other_string, integer_string);
        strcat(other_string, "]");
        c[p]= other_string;
    }
    cout << "Enter the character :";
    cin >> abc;

    for (p = 0; p < z; p++){
        if(g[p] == abc){
            cout <<abc<< "=a[" << p + 1 << "]"<< endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
};

//--------------------------------------------------------------
int main(){

    base b;
    b.array();

    return 0;
}
```

Could you tell me what is the problem in my program?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

`if ((g[i] >= 'a' && g[i] <= 'z') || (g[i] <= 'A' && g[i] >= 'Z'))`

to

`if ((g[i] >= 'a' && g[i] <= 'z') || (g[i] >= 'A' && g[i] <= 'Z'))`

and deleting the three ` , two in the first line and one in the last line.

---

**UPDATE**

Adding `#incude <cctype>` to the head of the code and using

`if (islower(g[i]) || isupper(g[i]))`

is better. To avoid depending to the character code.

`if (isalpha(g[i]))` may also work.

Comment: You should be aware that there is no guarantee that the alphabetic letters are contiguous or in any particular order. The only guarantee C or C++ gives about characters is that the characters '0' through '9' are contiguous and in the expected order.

Comment: @FredK Thank you. Edited.